# News feed imagecreatefromjpg() error in batch

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm pulling a news feed and doing batch imagecreatefromjpg() in a loop but I'm getting this error.

> Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known in
>   /home4/index.php on line 90

It works fine when I just do one image but in a loop, it errors out. Should there be a onComplete handler of some sort for each image, maybe it's doing it too fast?

I'm just grabbing the average color of each feed image.

```
$filename = $inimage;    
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);
$pixel = imagecreatetruecolor(1, 1);
imagecopyresampled($pixel, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $width, $height);
$rgb = imagecolorat($pixel, 0, 0);
$color = imagecolorsforindex($pixel, $rgb);
$image_r = $color['red'];
$image_g = $color['green'];
$image_b = $color['blue'];
```

thanks.

Comment: strange that I added '@' error suppression to imagecreatefromjpg and added an error catch condition, it works. No idea why.

          $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    if(!$image) {
     echo "error loading image";
    } else {

Comment: I wound up using imageMagick to do this instead. It's a little slower but generates less errors. Make sure to catch imageMagick's exceptions.